# How to disable Hyper-V in command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, hypervisor

I'm trying to open VMware, it says that VMware player and Hyper-V are not compatible. I found it [here](https://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/windows-8-1-vmware-player-and-hyper-v-are-not-compatible/), but it's not working using the command it offers.

I tried to see the help, found that there's `/hypervisorsettings` option there. But still not work with it, it says `The parameter is incorrect`.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I found a working way here: `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V`
and
`dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All`, but still don't know how `bcdedit` works.

Comment: this link (https://pswalia2u.medium.com/fully-disable-hyper-v-to-turn-back-to-vmware-virtualbox-159812bee71a) worked for me. For enterprise users, this solution will trigger BitLocker during restart, be aware!

Answer (score 359, accepted):

In an *elevated* Command Prompt write this :

To disable:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

To enable:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Restart to take effect.

Comment: I even forgot this question. I used this actually back then, but it didn't work. Anyway, it works now. Thanks.

Comment: In case you don't specifically need a command line solution but rather just something really simple and quick, you might use my tool [Hyper-V Switch](https://github.com/dg9ngf/HyperVSwitch) that uses the bcdedit method internally and puts a one-click GUI over it. Works on my Windows 10 computer.

Comment: Worked fine on Windows 10 1607

Comment: Worked on Win 10 (1803), though i had to reboot twice somehow.

Comment: For me that did not work even after also uninstalling Hyper-V in windows features. I also had to uninstall Internet Explorer 11 in windows features.

Comment: auto does not make much. You must activate sandbox to make android work for example, WSA.

Answer (score 45):

You can have a Windows 10 configuration with and without Hyper-V as follows in an Admin prompt:

```
bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 10 no Hyper-V"
```

find the new id of the just created "Windows 10 no Hyper-V" bootentry.

To find the new id, type "bcdedit" and then look for identifier `{XXX}` in the added boot loader configuration. eg. `{094a0b01-3350-11e7-99e1-bc5ec82bc470}`

```
bcdedit /set {094a0b01-3350-11e7-99e1-bc5ec82bc470} hypervisorlaunchtype Off
```

After rebooting you can choose between Windows 10 with and without Hyper-V at startup

Comment: If you run this command on PowerShell, make sure to put the `{current}` and `{GUID}` between `" "` like: `"{current}"`

Answer (score 31):

This command works

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

Run it then agree to restart the computer when prompted.

I ran it in elevated permissions PowerShell on Windows 10, but it should also work on Win 8 or 7.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without a reboot?

Comment: And what about re-enabling Hyper-V again via cmd? Thank you!

Comment: This command fully removes HyperV feature with it's files and programs. The bcdedit command is best to disable it and run VirtualBox or VMware instead of it.

Comment: My Hyper-V installation decided to give up on me for no reason (i’m running Windows 10 Pro v1703 build 15063.786).  I’ve tried to (un/re)install it via Windows Features menu, Powershell and DISM. They all gave no error but as soon as i try to create/add a new VM, and want to finish the last step, Hyper-V throws an error that it couldn’t open/access something because an object doesn’t appear to exist (dutch screenshot): https://i.imgur.com/07hem57.png Same story when running it with elevated/admin privileges. Apparently its not possible to fully restore/repair the Hyper-V product/modules...

Answer (score 20):

Command line:

`dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:microsoft-hyper-v-all`

If anyone is getting:

> We couldn’t complete the updates, Undoing changes

after trying to disable the Hyper-V, try uninstalling Hyper-V virtual network adapters from your Device Manager->Network Adapters

Comment: This causes windows update fails, thanks for the info

Comment: well it bypassed the windows update failing part for me

Comment: thanks, it worked while repairing windows from the command line

Answer (score 8):

Open a command prompt as admin and run this command:

```
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

After a reboot, Hyper-V is still installed but the Hypervisor is no longer running. Now you can use VMware without any issues.

If you need Hyper-V again, open a command prompt as admin and run this command:

```
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Comment: Is there any difference/advantage in using `bcdedit /set {current} ...` over `bcdedit /set ...`?

Comment: Now Windows 10 hung up on boot as a result of this command. What should I do ?

Answer (score 4):

Open command prompt as admin and write :

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Comment: Now Windows 10 hung up on boot as a result of this command. What should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

The OP had the best answer for me and it appears that others have figured out the -All addition as well. I set up two batch files, then shortcuts to those so you can set the Run As Admin permissions on them, easy-peasy.

Batch Off

```
Call dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

Batch On

```
Call dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
```

Right-click -> create desktop shortcut.
Right-click the shortcut -> properties -> under the shortcut tab -> Advanced -> Run as admin

Answer (score 1):

you can use my script.
paste code lines to notepad and save as vbs(for example  switch_hypervisor.vbs)

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim backupfile
Dim record
Dim myshell
Dim appmyshell
Dim myresult
Dim myline
Dim makeactive
Dim makepassive
Dim reboot
record=""
Set myshell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

If WScript.Arguments.Length = 0 Then
    Set appmyshell  = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    appmyshell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ RunAsAdministrator", , "runas", 1
    WScript.Quit
End if




Set backupfile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not (backupfile.FileExists("C:\bcdedit.bak")) Then
    Set myresult = myshell.Exec("cmd /c bcdedit /export c:\bcdedit.bak")
End If

Set myresult = myshell.Exec("cmd /c bcdedit")
Do While Not myresult.StdOut.AtEndOfStream
    myline = myresult.StdOut.ReadLine()

    If myline="The boot configuration data store could not be opened." Then
        record=""
        exit do
    End If
    If Instr(myline, "identifier") > 0 Then
        record=""
        If Instr(myline, "{current}") > 0 Then
            record="current"
        End If
    End If
    If Instr(myline, "hypervisorlaunchtype") > 0 And record = "current" Then
        If Instr(myline, "Auto") > 0 Then
            record="1"
            Exit Do
        End If
        If Instr(myline, "On") > 0 Then
            record="1"
            Exit Do
        End If
        If Instr(myline, "Off") > 0 Then
            record="0"
            Exit Do
        End If
    End If
Loop

If record="1" Then
    makepassive = MsgBox ("Hypervisor status is active, do you want set to passive? ", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
    Select Case makepassive
    Case vbYes
        myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off"
        reboot = MsgBox ("Hypervisor chenged to passive; Computer must reboot. Reboot now? ", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
        Select Case reboot
            Case vbYes
                myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  shutdown /r /t 0"
        End Select
    Case vbNo
        MsgBox("Not Changed")
    End Select
End If

If record="0" Then
    makeactive = MsgBox ("Hypervisor status is passive, do you want set active? ", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
    Select Case makeactive
    Case vbYes
        myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto"
        reboot = MsgBox ("Hypervisor changed to active;  Computer must reboot. Reboot now?", vbYesNo, "Hypervisor")
        Select Case reboot
            Case vbYes
                myshell.run "cmd.exe /C  shutdown /r /t 0"
        End Select
    Case vbNo
        MsgBox("Not Changed")
    End Select
End If

If record="" Then
        MsgBox("Error: record can't find")
End If
```

Comment: Normally, one should attempt to explain what a code snippet does/how it works when answering a question.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz looks self-explanatory to me. The script will just set the hypervisorlaunchtype to auto or off and also export current settings through the bcdedit command.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the OP's question, but if you have tried all the commands and Hyper-V shows as disabled, **BUT still unable to start a virtualisation software** like VirtualBox or VMWare and just so it happened that you had enabled WSL2 on your machine

Following solution might will work for you.

Go to `Control Panel` > `Programs & Features` > `Turn Windows Feature On/OFF`

Here is the catch, All the three below should be disabled/unchecked.

- Virtual Machine Platform
- Windows Hypervisor Platform
- Windows Subsystem for Linux

Restart!

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of stack overflow and all didn't works. But this works for me:

1. Open System Configuration
2. Click Service tab
3. Uncheck all of Hyper-V related

Answer (score 0):

I found the perfect solution on https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/enabling-hypervisor-auto-start-boot-configuration-database-bcd/

It wasn't working with given commands. But when you go to Power Shell and use command CMD then enter on or off with
bcdedit /set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype [off or on chose any]
then it worked without any issue.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31860084)

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it in the following way:**

**1. bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off**
[image]

**result [FAILED!]**

**2. bcdedit /set {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} hypervisorlaunchtype Off**

[image]

**result [FAILED!]**

**3. Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All**

[image]

**result [FAILED!]**

***The error is that I am not logged in as an administrator at the command prompt as a result all the steps above [FAIL!]***

**it should be like this:**

**1. open windows search**
[image]

**2. search cmd**
[image]

**3. Right click on Command Prompt**
[image]

**4. Click run as administrator**

**5. type in cmd bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off**
[image]

**and see already [SUCCESSFUL√]**