# PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Tags: android, node.js, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to run my first Ionic app but i'm getting this error where it does not find my phone and does not find the emulator to run either.

```
C:\Users\MART\Dropbox\Ionic\myapp>ionic run android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\MART\Dropbox\Ionic\myapp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\MART\Dropbox\Ionic\myapp

add to body class: platform-android

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\MART\Dropbox\Ionic\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\1.8.0_20\jdk1.8.0_20

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.

:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest   
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE 
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
:validateSigningDebug
:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE    
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4.105 secs

Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Users/MART/Dropbox/Ionic/myapp/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\MART\Dropbox\Ionic\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\1.8.0_20\jdk1.8.0_20

No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator


No emulator specified, defaulting to Nexus

Waiting for emulator to start...

PANIC: Cannot
 find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

...........................................................................

I have this installed in my android manager

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't have an environment variable for `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`, apparently.

Comment: Regarding not seeing your device, run `adb devices` and ensure you have USB debugging enabled

Comment: @cricket_007 how do I set up my environment for **ANDROID_SDK_ROOT** and where do I run **adb devices** is it in the terminal?

Comment: You should do an internet search for "windows environment variables", and yes you run `adb devices` in the terminal. Again, assuming `adb` is in your `PATH`, which again, is an environment variable. I'm sure there is some Ionic "getting started" documentation that goes over all of this

Comment: After setting the path of AVD and SDK as Hitesh Sahu said, don't forget to reboot your computer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329799/how-to-resolve-emulator-panic-cannot-find-avd-system-path-please-define-andr. After setting `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` restart a computer.

Answer (score 54):

I have same issue when I run my ionic 2 app on windows (**ionic run android**), and I solve it by following these steps, hope it will help you.

1- Start your **Android Studio**.

2- Create a **New Project** to be able to create or delete virtual devices.

3- Delete any virtual devices if found.

4- and create virtual device via **AVD manager** as shown below .

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: In my case, I opted not to delete existing virtual devices, which were created by Visual Studio 2017 for Windows (I am using Windows 10). The existing virtual device names start with "Visual Studio android 23" and target arm/x86 and phone/tablet. 

Android Studio does not support Hyper-V, so I had to [turn off Hyper-V](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line). After following the steps indicated above, everything worked for me. I selected the "Galaxy Nexus" emulator.

At time of writing, I was using Ionic `3.9.2`.

Answer (score 21):

AVD cant find SDK root, possibly because they are in a different directory.Set your environment variables as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Just a note. When you set `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` as the root of your SDK (like above) Android Studio will warn you not to do this when it loads up (in the Event Log)

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to run it on a Kindle Fire. Enable ADB on the Kindle Fire and via your project: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tablets/connecting-adb-to-device.html#install-the-usb-driver-windows-users

I used VS code and the built in terminal running the command: `ionic cordova run android`

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was a wrong `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable on mac, I had to use the homebrew version. Added this to the `.zshrc`:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$(brew --prefix)/share/android-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and none of the answers here solved my issue, I think the reason in my case was either Ionic framework or and most probably Native Script framework. Native Script uses the Android Studio emulator to link to their mobile apps so they change the Andriod Studio emulator's path.
What I did to solve the issue:

1.Unistall Ionic, Cordova, and Native Script - I'm not sure if this
    step is necessary

2- Uninstall Android Studio and deleting the folder Android in AppData/Local folder

3- Install Andriod Studio and make sure not to import settings

**1- Unistall Ionic, Cordova, and Native Script** I'm not sure if this
    step is necessary

For Window system

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm uninstall -g nativescript
```

**2- Uninstall Android Studio**

- Uninstall Android Studio from control panel
- Delete the folder users/${yourUserName}/appData/Local/Android (Show hidden files to see appData folder)

**3- Reinstall Android Studio**

- Make sure not to import settings

After that you might want to install the frameworks again, I did not

Answer (score -1):

First try this:
If you are using a device. then just ensure that the device is well-connected.
Check in the android studio that, the device is online. This error pops up usually when the device is offline.

If it does not work,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711435/6747251