# How to resolve 'Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I created an AVD with 8.0. when I'm starting the AVD, it crashes and gives this error:

> Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

I tried to resolve it by a previous answers available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value), but none of them are working. I also tried defining AVD path in system settings, but that also didn't worked.

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 and system image for AVD 8.0 (Oreo)(API level 26).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I solved my issue like this...

Go to '*My Computer*'-> '*Properties*' ->'*Advance System Settings*' -> '*Environment Variables*' -> inside 'System Variables' add "**ANDROID_SDK_ROOT**" or "**ANDROID_HOME**" and inside this set the path of your AVD.

After that **Restart** your Computer. You must **Restart** your computer, otherwise it won't work.

This method worked for me, situations may be different in other cases.
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value) for more information.

Comment: set the path of your 'Emulator' if the path of AVD is not working.

Comment: I give this the point particularly because none of the other stack overflow answers for this common issue talk about restarting your computer. I assume this is an aspect of environmental variables that I just didn't know about.

Comment: Restart terminal or restart computer? If restart computer why?

Comment: @rm-rfstar I don't know the exact answer, but it is an Advance System Setting and sometimes the OS needs a re-boot to apply those settings properly.

Answer (score 4):

It may be caused by improper SDK location.

Open 'SDK Manager'. Or in setting, click 'Appearance & Behavior'->'System Setting'->'Android SDK'.

Click 'Edit' besides 'Android SDK Location'. Set your Android SDK Location to 
'C:\Users\???\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk' (replace ??? with your account).

Make sure you have internet connection, or you have set proper proxy if you stays in some intranet. Then, android studio will detect that you have not installed SDK and SDK platform. Check them and click 'Next'.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after the Android Emulator update stopped midway due to some network issue. I tried the solutions given by Leon and Nick, but the issue persisted.

So I closed Android Studio and AVD manager and restarted both. I got the option to update Emulator after I reopened AVD manager. The issue got resolved after the update completed successfully.

Comment: Your experience is valuable

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Starting the emulator from AVD Manager I had no error. Launching from "Run.." in Android Studio, I get the error.
I solved (Windows) deleting (moving) all files from folder "C:\Users(user).android\avd, updating SDKTools from SDK Manager (Tools, SDKManager, SDKTools, select and update). And then from AVD Manager, adding new virtual device (what you like).