# PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT (in windows 10)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

While running an app on the `virtual device (AVD`) created on `Android studio` (in `Windows 10`), I am getting an error and panic.

***Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1***

While I have already defined my `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` in the environment variables.

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Was having the same issue. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value/44386974#44386974) helped to fix this issue. Refer to the answer given by [Oleg Cherr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899346/oleg-cherr) titled "Incomplete/corrupted SDK stucture"

Comment: I faced same issue yesterday and i solved it ..now today it occurs as same as ..stuck yaar:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve 'Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID\_SDK\_ROOT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329799/how-to-resolve-emulator-panic-cannot-find-avd-system-path-please-define-andr)

Comment: This fixed it for me https://betamode.de/2018/11/16/android-emulator-panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android_sdk_root-value/

Answer (score 36):

Open Android Studio and under the `Tools` you will find the `AVD manager`. Click on it and ensure that you have a valid virtual device with the SDK downloaded (click "download" in the Actions column if shown). Then ensure that the correct virtual device is selected on the toolbar.

Comment: This was my problem, fresh install of Android Studio on a Mac but it didn't install AVD stuff at all.  After that I was able to launch a simulator and run a sample app.

Answer (score 33):

define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT as environment variable where your SDK is residing, default path would be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk" and restart computer to take effect.

Comment: restart was not necessary in my case ... win 10 pro

Comment: I have to add till the `bin` folder as ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

Answer (score 15):

Go to **Control Panel**>>**System and Security**>>**System**>>**Advance system settings**>>**Environment Variables** then set variable value of **ANDROID_HOME** set it like this "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk" set username as your pc name, then restart your android studio. after that you can create your AVD again than the error will gone than it will start the virtual device.

Comment: The OP asked for ANDROID_SDK_ROOT not ANDROID_HOME

Comment: I had to define both ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and ANDROID_HOME to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk".

Comment: I think this happened to me because I was following a tutorial and installed the SDK from the command line, then it got installed in a different location when installed Android Studio. So, this solution worked for me.

Comment: @jsnfwlr I set ANDROID_HOME "...Local\Android\Sdk
and add Path ";%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools"

Answer (score 11):

My problem was solved by creating a Windows user without an accent or special characters and reinstalling android studio on that user. Another change is to change the environment variables:

**Left Click in My Computer > Advanced System Settings> Advanced > Environment Variables**

> ANDROID_HOME = c:\my_sdk_path
>
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = c:\my_sdk_path
>
> JAVA_HOME = c:\program files\Java\yourJavaPath

- the default path of SDK is c:\users\youruser\AppData\LocalAndroid\sdk

[image: Environment variables]

**Add in Path Variable the values:**

> 1. %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
> 2. %ANDROID_HOME%\tools

[image: path variables]

[image: path values]

After changes, restart windows and try again!

Answer (score 6):

For those coming here with a Mac:

I had the same issue and the problem was, I created an emulator with API Level 29 but removed that SDK and installed 28 instead.
The emulator that was not able to be launched anymore.

Therefore check the AVD Manager if your emulator really can be launched.

Answer (score 3):

Check C:\Users\User path. Change User directory name (may be something different name) from your alphabet to English alphabet. Warning: it is dangerous operation, learn it before changing. Android Studio can not access to AVD throw users\Your alphabet name\.android.

Answer (score 2):

[image: just create environment variable like this]

create environment variable like in the screenshot and make sure to replace with your sdk path in my case it was C:\Users\zeesh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk replace zeesh with your username and make sure to restart android studio to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

[Android Studio Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swUWF.png)

Make sure you have an Android Virtual Device selected to output the app to. In the picture I put on this post you can see I selected the Android Virtual Device "Nexus 5" as the output device. Doing this removed the error for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the argument: `-sysdir <Your_SDK_DIR>` and then check whether the error message displayed.

See also: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/1a15692cded92d66dea1a51389a3c4b9e3b3631a/android/emulator/main-emulator.cpp

Check out these clip you will find out the reason:

```cpp
// Sanity checks.
if (avdName) {
    if (!isCpuArchSupportedByRanchu(avdArch)) {
        APANIC("CPU Architecture '%s' is not supported by the QEMU2 emulator, (the classic engine is deprecated!)",
               avdArch);
    }
    std::string systemPath = getAvdSystemPath(avdName, sysDir);
    if (systemPath.empty()) {
        const char* env = getenv("ANDROID_SDK_ROOT");
        if (!env || !env[0]) {
            APANIC("Cannot find AVD system path. Please define "
                   "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT\n");
        } else {
            APANIC("Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT "
                   "value [%s]!\n",
                   env);
        }
    }
}
```

Then if you see ***emulator: ERROR: can't find SDK installation directory***, please check this solution.
[Android emulator errors with "emulator: ERROR: can't find SDK installation directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868458/android-emulator-errors-with-emulator-error-cant-find-sdk-installation-direc)

Answer (score 1):

If you experience this error when upgrading from one version of Android Studio to another and you have non-english characters in your home directory, the following could help.

Even though the error message are pointing at ANDROID_SDK_ROOT in my case non-english characters in the user folder which holds the avd-folder caused the problem (C:\Users\Björn\.android\avd).

In this case a simple solution is to **create a new avd-folder outside of the user folder and define an environment variable named ANDROID_AVD_HOME which points to the new folder** (for instance C:\andoid\avd) and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In Korean version of Windows 10, this problem happened because my Windows user name was in Korean not in English. After the user name was made again in English, the problem was cleared.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem when I was trying to move the android studio to another Drive as it was taking a lot of space in my C(Windows drive) Drive, Here's what fixed my problem:-

1. Copy the **C:\Users\ #YourUserName\ .android** folder to another drive,
2. Go to start environment variable make a new variable named
   **ANDROID_SDK_HOME** and add the path of the new location like mine is
   F:\Android AVD( **don't add .android to it** )
3. Then add ANDROID_SDK_HOME to the existing **Path** variable.
4. Open android studio, go to **configure --> AVD manager** and you'll see that you've successfully moved to a new location.

Answer (score -3):

Find the ANDROID_HOME path values from environment variable. In my case it is like C:\Users\RuwanPr\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk.
If this value not found please add ANDROID_HOME value as your sdk path.
(To go to environment variable right click on my computer -> Properties -> Advance System Settings -> Environment Variable )
Then open cmd on windows and go to sdk folder and then go to tools folder 
Type emulator -list-avds in comd. It will shows avd name list.
Then type emulator -avd avd-name.
Ex - think avd-name shows as J2_Api_22
emulator -avd J2_Api_22

Answer (score -3):

Update Android emulator alone from SDK tool

[image]