# Android Studio Emulator PANIC

Tags: android, android-studio

Any of my emulators won't work. Usually I use a physical device however right now I want to use advanced profiling feature and in order for it to work I need a device with API 27+ so I have set up an emulator for Google Pixel API 27. When I try to run the app the emulator crashes with following errors. 
   The default Haxm API 25 emulator doesn't return any  errors, Android Studio simply doesn't react when I try to choose it from the list. Nothing happens.

```
14:03   Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT

14:03   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID\_SDK\_ROOT value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39645178/panic-broken-avd-system-path-check-your-android-sdk-root-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329799/how-to-resolve-emulator-panic-cannot-find-avd-system-path-please-define-andr) post 
I have learned that solutions proposed in a link provided by @Rick M. do work but you have to **RESTART YOUR COMPUTER**