# Android Studio Emulator PANIC Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

All of a sudden the Android Studio emulator has stopped working. When I attempt to run a virtual device, I get the following error in the Event Log.

> Emulator: PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

So I checked to see what value the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` environment variable was set to, and it was empty. So I set it to `/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk` based on an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711435/5115932) to a similar question; but I still get the same error.

I tried deleting all of the virtual devices from the AVD Manager and creating a new one (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475465/5115932)), but no luck. I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling all of the SDK component packages; I still get the same error.

I cannot figure out what happened, or how to fix it. Could the `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` value I set be incorrect? (The value I set is the same as my `ANDROID_HOME` variable, which does point to the directory that contains the Android SDK).

The only thing I can think of that I haven't tried yet is to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio (I would rather try to avoid that if I can).

---

#### Update

Well... I deleted everything I could find relating to Android Studio.

```
~/.android
~/.AndroidStudio*
~/Applications/Android \Studio.app
~/Library/Android
~/Library/Application \Support/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
~/Library/Preferences/com.android.Emulator.plist
~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android.*
```

Then did a fresh install of Android Studio... and I'm still getting the same error. Did I miss something? What is causing this issue??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had been messing around with [CodeWorks for Android](https://developer.nvidia.com/codeworks-android) in order to get a working version of [Unreal Engine](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/Android/GettingStarted/index.html) that supports [ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unreal/quickstart). I never did get Unreal+ARCore to work, but the emulator in Android Studio had been working fine so I didn't think anything of it.

I noticed that whenever I ran the emulator the `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` would get reset to `/Users/{username}/Library/NVPACK/sdk/` and blank respectively. I removed the NVPACK library, and set both `ANDROID_HOME` and `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` to `/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/` and now the emulator works as expected again.

---

#### Update

I ended up going back to messing with Unreal Engine, and realizing I still needed CodeWorks installed to be able to launch an Android application from Unreal.

So I figured out that Android Studio was getting screwed up because `ANDROID_HOME` was set to `/Users/{username}/Library/NVPACK/sdk/` but in the SDK Manager the SDK location was still set to `/Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/`. I changed this value to `/Users/{username}/Library/NVPACK/sdk/` and after re-installing the SDK files, the emulator was up and running fine.