# Xamarin Studio Android Emulator Extremely Slow.... never launching

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator

Xamarin Studio Android Emulator Extremely Slow.... never launching
it wasn't like this before.
i tried reboot, recreate the emulator, no lucky.
please anyone has any idea? thanks.

[setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GC7c.png)

Comment: Maybe a problem related to hyper-v.  Try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line

Comment: Hi Jenny and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers. As I see it, your question could use more details. What version are you using? What OS? etc.

Comment: Have you install the [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows)?  And check  your `Intel Virtualization Technology` state in `Task Manager -> Performance -> Virtualization -> Enable or Disable`. If it is disabled, your Android Emulator will extremely slow.

Comment: thanks everyone, but my hyper-v is off, and Virtualization in enabled. :(

Comment: Intel HAXM is the reason. after i install it, it works nice. thank you  York.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced a slow Android emulator experience. I followed the link that Hugo posted and turning the hypervisor launchtype on and off worked for me.

For easier reference reasons i rewrite the steps to perform here

In an **elevated (Administrator mode)** Command Prompt write this :

To disable:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

To enable:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Then reboot your machine.