# Simple instructions needed for enabling and disabling Hyper V Docker

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I have asked something similar before, but I was wondering if someone could give me some very simple instructions for how I can turn off HyperV Container features so that I can use Virtual Box and then turn them back on to use Docker for Windows

At present I have the following message from Docker for Windows

"Hyper-V and Containers features are not enabled.
Do you want to enable them for Docker to be able to work properly?
Your computer will restart automatically.
Note: VirtualBox will no longer work."

I do NOT need both at the same time

I really need clear instructions as I do not want to be in a position where I get docker working then can never use Virtual Box again!

I have a requirement for using my existing Virtual Box VMs every now and then and I cannot be in a position where I cannot use them

Paul

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do below to disable

```
dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

and below to enable

```
dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

From PowerShell

To Disable

```
Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All
```

To Enable

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All
```

PS: Source threads

https://superuser.com/questions/540055/convenient-way-to-enable-disable-hyper-v-in-windows-8

[How to disable Hyper-V in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line)

Comment: Enabling using Powershell did not work completely. Docker was still saying hyper-v not enabled. "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto" worked.