# How to unable AMD-V on Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager

Tags: windows, installation, virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I set up a virtual machine (Linux - Ubuntu) on "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager" (Application). I can't start it because: 
"AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED)" (Error Msg upon attempt to start)

My desktop use Windows 10 and has Virtualization option supported and enabled, I also disabled Hyper-V as instructed here:
"[How to disable Hyper-V in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line)" (link), and closed my desktop after applying the change.

I still have "Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Manager/Settings/System/Acceleration" (path to option box) grayed out, which stop me from enabling AMD-V.

I'm clearly missing something to access this option and yet I have visualization enabled and Hyper-V disabled. Any leads would be appreciated.

Comment: If you down vote my post, can you tell me why? I'm trying my best to make my point clear to find what I'm missing

Comment: This isn’t a programming question.

Comment: Taking for example the tread I putted as a reference about disabling Hyper-V to set up a virtual-machine, I believe this question doesn't step out of bounds.

I'm just confused because I added filter that should be appropriate for what I'm looking for and these don't focus on "programming".

(another ex: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, having virtualization enabled and hyper-V disabled isn't enough apparently.

Asus BIOS wasn't something I'm used to, but if you go in the BIOS:

> advance setting/CPU

and you enable svm Mode, you should get access to a 64-bytes version of your virtual machine in the settings of the application you are using. From there, my virtual machine managed to start up without issues.

hope this help anyone...

Answer (score 0):

```
Your Virtualization is disabled so you need to enable it

**go to BIOS**
->Restart your system and click Fn+f2
next
**go to configuration**
click SVM and enable it (if you have AMD processor)
or 
Click intel virtual Technology and enable it (if you have intel processor)
```