# VMWare Workstation cannot run on Windows 10 after recent update to Windows 10

Tags: windows, vmware, hyper-v

I've Windows 10 Pro system, and use Hyper-V on that system. Due to the needs of device redirection doesn't works well with Hyper-V, I've installed VMWare Workstation 14.

I have to disable Hyper-V to make VMWare Workstation work, at beginning. It worked until last weekend <strike>, seems because of the QFE update</strike>. I just verified, it was not QFE but Feature update to Windows 10, version 1803 that triggered the problem with VMWare Workstation again.

1. After Windows update completed (after reboot), I tried to start a VM in VMWare. I get the error dialog complaining about Device/Credential Guard.

[image]

2. Following the instruction in this link: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2146361, and after the reboot, I get another complaint about incompatibility with Hyper-V.

[image]

3. After reset the Hyper-V selection in Windows Feature or confirm that HyperV is not already removed, and reboot, the first error came back.

It gets in a loop of error complaining about Device Guard and complaining about Hyper-V for VMWare.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, thanks to the answer from communities of VMWare: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/588526

The issue is now gone, by applying the following change:

1. Disable credential guard by using readiness tool from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337, with this command: DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.2.ps1 -disable
2. Disable Hyper-V by using PowerShell command: Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V
3. Reboot and accept to boot without CG/DG.

Although I don't like that VMWare cannot work together with device guard from system, I get my VM working for the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the link that helped. I need to go further, vmware now wants that i delete the hyper-v role from the system. Need to check for that

Comment: Microsoft Windows Hyper-V as a role is misleading it's a Type 1 hypervisor that takes over the system between the hardware and the OS, Windows then runs in Hyper-V. VMware Workstation is a Type 2 hypervisor (runs as an OS application) that should be able to run in Windows even if the host OS is managed by Hyper-V.

Comment: How to dual-boot both VMWare and Hyper-V: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43843318/603516

Answer (score 6):

1- run cmd as admin

2- run : bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

3- reboot

let me knew if it works please

good luck

Answer (score 3):

here are the few steps for you to solve this issue:

1. Disable the HvHost service (and any other services with prefix Hyper-V if needed) from windows TaskManager(Ctrl+Alt+Del)
2. use the tool from [the official website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337)
3. Uncompress the downloaded zip file to your own directory, take **C:\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.5** here for instance.
4. Run Windows PowerShell as admin, type the following two commands:

   `cd C:\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.5`
   `.\DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.5.ps1 -Disable`
5. Reboot

Answer (score 1):

Adrian at https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security/cannot-disable-memory-integrity-core-isolation-in/29ac5ce4-30d2-47d1-ab17-734980fd287b 
says "I think it's a bug that this cannot be disabled via UI but fortunately it's possible through the registry by setting the following key to 0:"

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity\Enabled

This worked for me as well [Windows 10 Pro Version 1803(OS Build 17134.112, VMWare Workstation 14 Pro Version 14.1.2]

Comment: Thank you for your message. I'll try this out when I have time:)