# Problem with bcdedit command on Windows 10

Tags: cmd, windows-10

Found this commands:

- bcdedit /copy {current} /d "Windows 10 no Hyper-V"
- bcdedit /set {094a0b01-3350-11e7-99e1-bc5ec82bc470} hypervisorlaunchtype Off

on this post

[How to disable Hyper-V in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line)

My Win 10 machine now ask me for the 2 options (win10 or Win10 without Hyperview), but remain on Welcome screen, after askying me for pw, for several hours without finish the starting

Help! Help! Help!

Comment: You ran someone else's GUID. If you don't understand something don't do it. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options

Comment: No i ran the guid returned from the first command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run Windows on Safe Mode.

First I tried to delete the new boot entry

- bcdedit /enum

found the guid of the new boot entry

- bcdedit /delete {guid}

reboot, not solved.

Another time Windows Safe Mode. Used a point of restore of 2 days before. Solved.

Maybe the work machine which had the problem was too old or maybe the OS was not clean having too much sw installed and removed during  years...